# TwitterにAVCaptureSessionで撮影した動画をアップロードできない

Tags: swift, ios, twitter, avfoundation, social-framework

iPhoneのカメラで15秒間動画を撮影し、その動画をTwitterにアップロードしようとすると「Request status was 413」とエラーが返ってきて動画をアップロードできません。 
アップロードしている最中にログに「SLRequestBodyInputStream  read:maxLength: Total 6692864 bytes streamed, total length is 15382475」というようなものが表示され続けています。（表示されるたびにTotal 6692864の数字が増えていっています） 
Twitterにアップロードしている部分のコードは以下になります。

```
class TwitterSharer: NSObject {

var videoPathURL: URL
var account: ACAccount!
let twitterUploadURL = URL(string: "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
let twitterStatusURL = URL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")

init(url: URL) {
    videoPathURL = url
}

func authAccount(completion: @escaping (_ error: Bool)->Void) {
    let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
    let accountType:ACAccountType = accountStore.accountType(withAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)
    accountStore.requestAccessToAccounts(with: accountType, options: nil) { (granted, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("error! \(error)")
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        if !granted {
            print("error! Twitterアカウントの利用が許可されていません")
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        let accounts = accountStore.accounts(with: accountType) as! [ACAccount]
        if accounts.count == 0 {
            print("error! 設定画面からアカウントを設定してください")
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        print("アカウント取得完了")

        self.account = accounts.first!

        guard let mediaData = NSData(contentsOf: self.videoPathURL) else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        self.postMedia(tweet: "test", mediaData: mediaData as Data, fileSize: String(mediaData.length), completion: completion)
    }
}

func post(completion: @escaping (_ error: Bool)->Void) {
    authAccount(completion: completion)
}

private func postMedia(tweet: String, mediaData: Data, fileSize: String, completion: @escaping (_ error: Bool)->Void) {
    var json: [String: Any]!

    // INIT リクエスト
    uploadVideoInitRequest(fileSize: fileSize, success: { (_ responseData: Data)->Void in
        do {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
        } catch {
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        let mediaIdString = json["media_id_string"] as! String

        // APPEND リクエスト
        self.uploadVideoAppendRequest(mediaData: mediaData, mediaIdString: mediaIdString, success: { () -> Void in

            // FINALIZE リクエスト
            self.uploadVideoFinalizeRequest(mediaIdString: mediaIdString, success: { (_ responseData: Data) -> Void in

                let statusRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter, requestMethod: .POST, url: self.twitterStatusURL, parameters: ["status" : tweet, "media_ids" : mediaIdString])

                statusRequest?.account = self.account

                // 動画をつけてツイート
                statusRequest?.perform { (responseData, urlResponse, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        completion(true)
                    } else {
                        completion(false)
                    }
                }
            }, completion: { (_ success: Bool) -> Void in
                if !success {
                    completion(false)
                }
            })
        }, completion: { (_ success: Bool) -> Void in
            if !success {
                completion(false)
            }
        })
    }, completion: { (_ success: Bool) -> Void in
        if !success {
            completion(false)
        }
    })
}

// INIT リクエスト
private func uploadVideoInitRequest(fileSize: String, success: @escaping (_ responseData: Data)->Void, completion: @escaping (_ error: Bool)->Void) {
    let initParams: [String: Any] = ["command": "INIT", "media_type": "video/mp4", "total_bytes": fileSize]
    let initRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter, requestMethod: .POST, url: self.twitterUploadURL, parameters: initParams)
    initRequest!.account = account
    initRequest!.perform { (responseData, urlResponse, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            success(responseData!)
        } else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }
    }
}

// APPEND リクエスト
private func uploadVideoAppendRequest(mediaData: Data, mediaIdString: String, success: @escaping () -> Void, completion: @escaping (_ error: Bool)->Void) {
    let appendParam: [NSString: Any] = ["command": "APPEND", "media_id": mediaIdString, "segment_index": "0"]
    let appendRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter, requestMethod: .POST, url: self.twitterUploadURL, parameters: appendParam)
    appendRequest?.addMultipartData(mediaData, withName: "media", type: "video/mov", filename: nil)
    appendRequest?.account = account
    appendRequest?.perform { (responseData, urlResponse, error) -> Void in

        if urlResponse!.statusCode < 300 && urlResponse!.statusCode >= 200 {
            success()
        } else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }
    }
}

// FINALIZE リクエスト
private func uploadVideoFinalizeRequest(mediaIdString: String, success: @escaping (_ responseData: Data) -> Void, completion: @escaping (_ error: Bool)->Void) {
    let finalizeParam: [NSString: Any] = ["command": "FINALIZE", "media_id": mediaIdString]
    let finalizeRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter, requestMethod: .POST, url: self.twitterUploadURL, parameters: finalizeParam)
    finalizeRequest?.account = account
    finalizeRequest?.perform { (responseData, urlResponse, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            success(responseData!)
        } else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }
    }
}

}
```

試しに撮影する動画を軽くしようと思い、以下のようにAVCaptureSessionにAVCaptureSessionPresetLowを設定すると動画をTwitterにアップロードできるようになります。

```
func setUpCamera() {
    let devices = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .front).devices

    do {
        let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: devices?.first!) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
        captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
        captureSession.addInput(audioInput);
    } catch {

    }
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    captureSession.addOutput(fileOutput)
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow    //この行を追加するとアップロードできる
    captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

しかし動画がかなり荒いです。 
普通に撮影した状態で動画をTwitterにアップロードしたいのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか？ 
Twitterに動画をアップロードする際に画質が少し荒くなるのは仕方ないことなのでしょうか？ 
いろいろ調べて見たもののこれ以上どうすればいいかわからないので、どなたかわかる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swiftで動画アップロードを書いたことは無いですが…………

Twitterの動画アップロードAPI(chunked media)は、リクエスト1つあたりのPOSTを5MB以下に抑える必要があります。(おそらくこれを越えているため413が返されているのでしょう。)

ではファイル自体5MB以下に抑える必要があるのかというとそうではなく、5MB以下ごとに分割してPOSTすれば500MB辺りまではまず行けるようです。

なお、Twitterは現在確か2種類以上のサイズにアップロードされた動画をエンコードしてたはずですが、どちらにせよある程度の画質低下は不可避です…………

※なお、30秒を越える動画のアップロードにはasync uploadが必要です: [CoreTweetで30秒を超える動画をTwitterにアップロードしてみる | ぴんくいろにっき](https://blog.hinaloe.net/2016/06/23/upload-more-long-video-with-coretweet/#API)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
そうなんですね、ある程度の画質低下は不可避なのですね。
分割すればPOSTができると言うことなのでちょっと分割してアップロードしてみます。

Comment: http://somtd.hatenablog.com/entry/20120229/1330528157
このサイトを参考に圧縮を試してみると10分の1以下に圧縮することができました。ありがとうございました。